# Java: Where is InputStream's read() method implemented when reading from System.in

Tags: java, inputstream, system.in

Abstract class `InputStream` says that subclasses need to implement method `read()` which reads `one byte` and then turns it into an `unsigned int`.

`System.in` is an `InputStream` and I can do:

```
 int i = System.in.read();
```

My question is.. where is this method implemented? How come it works? Maybe an odd question but I'm trying to find out what's happening under the hood and since I'm using an object of class InputStream and not one of its subclasses, I'm wondering where the actual method is implemented and why it works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`InputStream` is the type of `System.in`, and not it's class (since `InputStream` cannot be directly instantiated as it is abstract).

Consider:

```
Object obj = "123";
```

The type of the variable `obj` is `Object`, but the instance referenced by `obj` is an instance of `String`. When `toString()` is called on `obj` the implementation in `String` is used, and not the implementation in `Object`.

The same goes for `System.in`. The actual instance stored there will be some subclass of `InputStream`, which will have its own implementation of any abstract methods. If you want to know the class of the instance stored in `System.in` then you can call `System.in.getClass()`.

Comment: Cool! In my case it was a BufferedInputStream .. got the concept! Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

System.in is *an implementation of* an InputStream which has the read method implemented.

If you take a look in the source of `System` you can see it's really a `FileInputStream` opening the file handle 0 (which is the standard input stream). But this isn't really relevant. The only thing you need to know is that you can read from it. It isn't relevant if its a `FileInputStream`, a `StringInputStream` or some other native `InputStream`. That's the whole point of interfaces. You can mostly just program against an interface without worrying about the specific implementation.

Comment: So would one say that both subclasses and implementations of class InputStream has to have the method implemented then?

Comment: `System.in` is not an implementation of anything. It's an instance of an object of a class that extends `InputStream`.

Comment: Aha.. and the actual class itself os not InputStream, it's just something that extends InputStream then? Got it! Thanks.. sorry if it was a silly questions...

Comment: I posted this as an answer with a bit more detail. NP

Comment: @Isaac: So, if System.in is an instance of an object of a class that extends InputStream, that instance of an object of a class is an implementation of InputStream ( `implements InputStream` ). Why, in your opinion, is it wrong to say that the instance stored in System.in is an implementation of InputStream?

Comment: It's a matter of technical terminology. By saying "implements `InputStream`", you imply that `InputStream` is an interface, which it isn't (it's an abstract class). Just wanted to avoid that confusion.

Comment: Alternatively, "`System.in` is an implementation of `InputStream`" may be interpreted as if `System.in` is a class.

Comment: Then again, I'm an ESL so I might be perceived as if I'm smoking something very cheap (which I don't).

Comment: I'm not even an ESL (had to google that), but I thought `InputStream` was an interface. My bad.

Answer (score 2):

What is System.in.read() ?

1) `System.in` returns `static InputStream in`

First of all *`InputStream`* Class is an *`abstract class`* with its *`read method also abstract`*, this means there could be n number of implementations for the read method .

**So whats happening behind the scenes ?**

*`System.in`* returns an instance of *`InputStream class on runtime`* i.e class which extends InputStream as we know all byte stream classes extends InputStream , so it can be any class extending InputStream class.
Now the `read method is called from that class which it actually extending InputStream.`

You can always check the instance provided for InputStream class by calling **System.in.getClass()**

Answer (score 1):

What's happening under the hood is this: the `in` attribute of the class `System` is assigned, at runtime, a reference to an object of some class `X`. That class `X` extends `InputStream`, and as such, it implements the `read` method.

You can't tell for sure (meaning, it's not specified anywhere) what class `X` is; all you know is that it extends `InputStream`. Different JDK's might use different classes.